# Rust -- How to call and pass a closure in an iteration?

Tags: rust, closures

I have an iteration:

```rust
fn foo<F>(mut callback: F)
    where F: FnMut(MyStruct)
{
    // produce an instance of MyStruct
    callback(my_struct);
    for ... { // some conditions
        foo(callback)
    }
}
```

And the closure may be:

```rust
let my_vec = vec![];
let mut callback = |my_struct: MyStruct| {my_vec.push(my_struct);};
foo(callback);
```

In my `for` loop, the ownership of `callback` is moved, so the code above doesn't work. I try to replace the parameter to `mut callback: &mut F`, and use `foo(&mut callback)`, which still doesn't work, and the compiler says "overflow evaluating the requirement".

Comment: Hi there! "*the compiler says 'overflow evaluating the requirement'*" -> what compiler version are you using? Because your solution [works on the current stable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39e327fe692793fb587aa6828e78feca). And I'd say that this is also *the* solution to your problem basically. Please also provide the full error message if using a newer compiler (`rustup update`) doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt My rust version is 1.38.0, and [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d935729cdf82ad3e0822a4b72e04fc0e)'s wrong output is the same as mine. Maybe the problem is how I call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `&mut` when recursing:

```
fn foo<F>(callback: &mut F)
    where F: FnMut(MyStruct)
{
    let my_struct = MyStruct;
    callback(my_struct);
    for _ in 0..3 { // some conditions
        foo(callback);      // <- HERE
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55e55336b624613c9cea675179d627fa) (note: this overflows the stack when run due to the infinite recursion of `foo`. I assume that your real code uses a loop condition that causes the recursion to terminate…)